# Google map zoom out not working in collect new LatLng in the Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I want to zoom out in the google map but I have a problem. I emit the new LatLng when I move the map and I used moveCamera codes in the collected. Cause when I want to zoom out the camera the new LatLng is collect and map zoom back to same zoom level. How can I fix it?

**ViewModel Codes:**

In the viewModel I have a `MutableStateFlow()` called `lastSelectedLocation` wish save the last location (click current location button value or pin value with move the map)

```
@HiltViewModel
class PickLocationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val clientNavigator: ClientNavigator,
    private val checkLocationIsSetDataStore: CheckLocationIsSetDataStore,
    private val isLocationSetDataStore: IsLocationSetDataStore
) :
    ViewModel(), ClientNavigator by clientNavigator {
    private val _lastSelectedLocation = MutableStateFlow(getInitialLocation())
    val lastSelectedLocation = _lastSelectedLocation.asStateFlow()

    val _isMapEditable = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isMapEditable: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isMapEditable

     fun getInitialLocation(): LocationModel =
        LocationModel(
            lat = Constants.IF_LOCATION_LAT_NOT_SET,
            lng = Constants.IF_LOCATION_LNG_NOT_SET
        )


    fun setLocation(loc: LocationModel) {
        _lastSelectedLocation.value = loc
    }

    fun saveLocation(callBack: () -> Unit) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            checkLocationIsSetDataStore.set(lastSelectedLocation.value)
            callBack.invoke()
        }
    }

    fun savedLocationIsSet() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            isLocationSetDataStore.set(true)
        }
    }

    fun onEvent(event: PickLocationEvent, context: Context) {
        when (event) {
            is PickLocationEvent.GetCurrentLocation -> {
                getCurrentLocation(context)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getCurrentLocation(context: Context) {
        val fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
        try {

            val locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation

            locationResult.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    task.result?.let {
                        setLocation(LocationModel(it.latitude, it.longitude))
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("Exception", " Current User location is null")
                }
            }

        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            Log.d("Exception", "Exception:  $e.message.toString()")
        }
    }

}
```

**Map codes:**

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@ExperimentalPermissionsApi
@Composable
private fun MapViewContainer(
    mapView: MapView,
    navigatorViewModel: PickLocationViewModel
) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    rememberMultiplePermissionsState(
        listOf(
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        )
    ).apply {
        FeatureThatRequiresPermission(
            multiplePermissionsState = this, permissionsState = {
                permissionsState = it
                if (!it) {
                    return@FeatureThatRequiresPermission
                }
            })
        val locationState = MutableStateFlow(navigatorViewModel.getInitialLocation())
        LaunchedEffect(navigatorViewModel.lastSelectedLocation) {
            navigatorViewModel.lastSelectedLocation.collect {
                locationState.value = it
            }
        }
        AndroidView(
            factory = { mapView }
        ) {
            mapView.getMapAsync { map ->
                map.apply {
                
                    uiSettings.apply {
                        isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
                        isZoomControlsEnabled = true
                        isZoomGesturesEnabled = false
                    }

                    navigatorViewModel.apply {
                        scope.launch {
                            locationState.collect {
                                val position = LatLng(
                                    it.lat,
                                    it.lng
                                )
                                moveCamera(
                                    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                        position,
                                        Constants.ZOOM_CAMERA
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        scope.launch {
                            setOnCameraIdleListener {
                                val cameraPosition = map.cameraPosition
                                setLocation(
                                    LocationModel(
                                        lat = cameraPosition.target.latitude,
                                        lng = cameraPosition.target.longitude
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fwiw it might be comparing with what's in https://github.com/joreilly/GalwayBus ....the functionality might not exactly match but I do see one difference at least in `setOnCameraIdleListener` logic

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Thanks. I used this source. I should create a boolean to check the map running is first time